# how to keep image on button as selected on cell in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my code is working till here

```
-(void)imageStatusChanged:(id)sender{

    if(mode.IsCompleted==TRUE){
        mode.IsCompleted=FALSE;     
    }
    else {
        mode.IsCompleted=TRUE;
    }
    if([imagemodal UpdateStatus:mode.modeId :mode.IsCompleted]==TRUE)
    {
        //update the image
        if (mode.IsCompleted) {
            [modeCompletedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pad-Checkbox-Done-N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [modeCompletedButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
        }
        else{
        [modeCompletedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pad-Checkbox-Inactive-N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [modeCompletedButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
        }

    }
}
```

if i touch the button the image is changing it working good.But  for eg if i click any button the image is change if go other page and come again same page where i selected button for tick and untick then my my image is disapper .On selected i stor the bool value 0 is untick and 1 is tick image what i have to do in my code so when i close application and again run then selected image should display how to do please help me

Answer (score 1):

better to use NSUserDefaults, same case of problem is in my app but it's in table cell. In table view using indexpath.